# Interleaved VBO with Float and Byte

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I want to store three float values and two byte-values in an interleaved OpenGL vbo. 
Unfortunately, the rendered data is obviously not correct. 
When I rendered the same data with two different VBOs, all worked fine, so I don't assume that there is a problem with my shaders.

```
/*
 * 20^3 blocks per chunk, 6 faces per block, 3 vertices per face
 * max. every second face can be visible
 */
private static final int MAX_FLOAT_AMOUNT = 20 * 20 * 20 * 6 * 3 / 2;

/*
 * 20^3 blocks per chunk, 6 faces per block, 2 bytes per face
 * max. every second face can be visible
 */
private static final int MAX_BYTE_AMOUNT = 20 * 20 * 20 * 6 * 2 / 2;

private int dataVboIndex;

protected int vaoId;
protected int indicesCount;

protected boolean isInitialized = false;


public static ByteBuffer dataFloatBuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(4 * MAX_FLOAT_AMOUNT + MAX_BYTE_AMOUNT);

DefaultChunkVao(int indiciesVboId) {
    init();
}

DefaultChunkVao(boolean initialize) {
    if(initialize) init();
}

private void init() {
    isInitialized = true;

    // bind vao
    vaoId = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

    //create vbo
    dataVboIndex = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataVboIndex);

    dataFloatBuffer.clear();
    dataFloatBuffer.position(4 * MAX_FLOAT_AMOUNT + MAX_BYTE_AMOUNT);
    dataFloatBuffer.flip();

    // allocate memory
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataFloatBuffer, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4 + 2, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, 3 * 4 + 2, 3 * 4);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, 3 * 4 + 2, 3 * 4 + 1);

    // unbind vao
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

public void updateData(float[] data) {
    if(!isInitialized) init();

    dataFloatBuffer.clear();
    for(int counter = 0; counter < data.length; counter+=0) {
        dataFloatBuffer.putFloat(data[counter++]);
        dataFloatBuffer.putFloat(data[counter++]);
        dataFloatBuffer.putFloat(data[counter++]);

        dataFloatBuffer.put((byte) data[counter++]);
        dataFloatBuffer.put((byte) data[counter++]);
    }
    dataFloatBuffer.flip();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataVboIndex);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, dataFloatBuffer);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    this.indicesCount = data.length / 5;
}
```

The `MAX_FLOAT_AMOUNT` and the `MAX_BYTE_AMOUNT` constants contains the amount of floats resp. bytes per VBO. Am I right in assuming that I have to multiply the amount of floats with 4 when I determine the capacity of the `ByteBuffer` since every float has 4 bytes?

And what did I make wrong that I the my byte values are always 0 in the shader?

---

**EDIT**: I was able to reproduce the issue with a simpler example. Here I want to store the position and two bytes in the VBO. In the fragment shader I check if the byte1 value is passed correctly. If so, the shader renders the shape green, else blue. Unfortunately, my shape is rendered blue, hence I assume that the byte1 value is not passed correctly.

**vertexShader**

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in int byte1;
in int byte2;

flat out int p_byte1;
flat out int p_byte2;

void main(void) {

    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1);

    p_byte1 = byte1;
    p_byte2 = byte2;
}
```

**fragmentShader**:

```
#version 400 core

flat in int p_byte1;
flat in int p_byte2;

out vec3 out_color;

void main(void) {
    if(p_byte1 == 45) {
        out_color = vec3(0, 1, 0);
    } else out_color = vec3(0, 0, 1);

}
```

**creating the VAO:**

```
vaoId = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
final int vbo = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

float[] data = {0, 0, 0, 20f, 20f, 1, 1, 1, 20f, 20f, 1, 0, 1, 20f, 20f, 0, 1, 1, 20f, 20f};
ByteBuffer dataBuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(4 * (3 * 4) + 1 * (2 * 4));
for(int counter = 0; counter < data.length; counter+=0) {
dataBuffer.putFloat(data[counter++]);
dataBuffer.putFloat(data[counter++]);
dataBuffer.putFloat(data[counter++]);

dataBuffer.put((byte) data[counter++]);
dataBuffer.put((byte) data[counter++]);
}
dataBuffer.flip();

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataBuffer, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4 + 2, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, 3 * 4 + 2, 3 * 4);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, 3 * 4 + 2, 3 * 4 + 1);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316179/copying-float-arrays-and-float-values-to-a-bytebuffer-java This answer has a lot of useful information about using floats within byte buffers

Comment: @httpdigest the cast isn't the problem, because when I replace `.put((byte) data[counter++]);` with `counter++; .put((byte) 45);` the problem does still exist. But when I replace the value from the VAO with 45 in the vertex shader the issue doesn't occur.

Comment: So how does the Vertex Shader look? You aren't using integer inout attribute types in the shader, or are you?

Comment: I have posted an example in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to my question. It is necessary to use `glVertexAttribIPointer` instead of `glVertexAttribPointer` for integer data types.

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4 + 2, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribIPointer(1, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 3 * 4 + 2, 3 * 4);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribIPointer(2, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 3 * 4 + 2, 3 * 4 + 1);
```